# List names of all available threads on Android

Tags: android

Need to get list names of all threads on device (not only active or running). Cant find any solution or ideas. Maybe someone knows is it possible implement with java(kotlin) or maybe native code... reflection:)

Looking for result like in Profiler with ALL threads:
[image: Profiler]

Comment: I didn't know threads have a name. I doubt it too.